# What is the default expiry period of a cookie?

Tags: jsp, cookies

I am working on jsp and came across "cookies".
I am aware of the functions related to getting, setting or checking cookies and also the expiry period setting is clear to me.
But just for the knowledge point of view, I wanted to know if there is any default expiry period for a cookie, in case i don't set it manually?
I tried Google, but could find absolutely no answers for this particular part.
I will really appreciate if anyone can throw some light on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default Expires value for a cookie is not a static time, but it creates a Session cookie. This will stay active until the user closes their browser/clears their cookies. You can override this as required.

Check this link(it isnt jsp but will help you)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookie.expires%28VS.80%29.aspx

**Setting the Expires property to MinValue makes this a session Cookie, which is its default value**

Check this tutorial on cookies

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_cookies_handling.htm

This will surely help you

Answer (score 1):

The default lifetime of a cookie set in a JSP page is the current browsing session only.
Once you restart the browser,the cookie no longer exists.